# How to use JQuery in Laravel (NPM)

Tags: jquery, laravel, npm

Im new to web development and I work with the Laravel framework. I use npm for handling with packages. But now I have a problem to implement JQuery. Bootstrap is implemented to larval and it works

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
```

In my Laravel project is in the package.json

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "0.*",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.1.10",
    "webpack": "2.2.1"
  }
```

Does that mean that Jquery is already in my project? But how looks the link like above from Bootstrap for jquery. For Bootstrap I have to compile new code (npm run dev) have I to do the same for Jquery?

Comment: You have to execute command `npm run dev` or `npm run production`. Check whole [this page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#running-mix). Running that command Laravel's mix will include jQuery into `app.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had a look at this for a laravel 10 project with jetstream livewire these are the steps I took to get jQuery working: open windows terminal `npm install jquery` added `'./node_modules/jquery/**/*.js'` to tailwind.config.js added `'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',` to vite.config.js then added this to my head tag `@vite('node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?commonjs-entry')` finally I added `import jQuery from 'jquery'; window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;` to bootstrap.js in `resources/js` this added jQuery.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure your `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js` got jQuery imported:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
```

Then you'll be able to use jQuery in your project.

Comment: After running `npm install jquery --save-dev`, placing this solution in the same named file before running `npm run dev` worked in Laravel 8! Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

JQuery is already installed within your project. To use it place the reference within your view.

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

and run `npm run dev`

Answer (score 0):

all the submitted answer are correct, but i want to add that you need to put reference for your js/app.js as that is where your javascript and jquery file is and you need it to make it work. MORE importantly, you need to write it in every views that requires spesific javascript/jquery function

```html
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```