# ReferenceError $ not defined in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I installed a fresh copy of Laravel 8 but I am unable to use $ in jQuery. I know that this is a frequent question here in SO link [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45393343/how-to-use-jquery-in-laravel-npm) but I am unable to jQuery in document ready.

Here are the steps that I have tried based on what I read in various SO and blogs:

`npm install jquery --save-dev` (someone said that jquery was removed from laravel 6 in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56794159))

`npm install jquery-ui --save-dev`

added in main.blade.php (under /body)

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

in bootstrap.js

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
```

in app.scss

```
@import "~jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css";
```

webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
    .sass("resources/sass/app.scss", "public/css")
    .sass("resources/scss/normalize.scss", "public/css")
    .sass("resources/scss/main.scss", "public/css")
    .sourceMaps();
```

run `npm run dev`

I know this is a very basic question but I don't know how to proceed.

**EDIT**
I got it working. I added `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>` under `</body>` it should have been inside `<head></head>`. The problem was when the app.js should have been declared.

Comment: [Try this](http://net-informations.com/jq/iq/defined.htm)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I did consider using cdn instead of using the npm install route but I wish to use npm install. If I am still unable to fix this by the end of the day, I will try the cdn route later.

Answer (score 0):

Kenneth,
Please put this line at starting of **'resources/js/app.js'** instead of bootstrap.js

`window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");`

Comment: Yes. I also tried adding this in app.js and/or bootstrap.js. Same result

Comment: also, in app.js, require("./bootstrap"); was already declared and inside bootsrap.js,  `window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");` was also declared