# Jquery only working when I code in the `app.js` file with Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-9

I have this issue with jquery, I want to be able to use it anywhere in my application.
I have installed it using `npm install jquery` and have imported it in my `app.js` file like this:

```
import $ from "jquery";
window.$ = $;
```

And in my livewire component, I have this code:

```
@push('scripts')
    <script>
        $(function () {
            alert("Hello");
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

With this code, I get the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

And finally, I have this in my blade layout file:

```
@livewireScripts
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
@stack('scripts')
```

This code is working only if I put it in the `app.js` file.

Answer (score 2):

try replacing your import with this one:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
```

credit: [How to use JQuery in Laravel (NPM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45393343/how-to-use-jquery-in-laravel-npm) Ikbel

if this didn't work, try adding an event of loading:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    $(function () {
        alert("Hello");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error!

Comment: try adding the jquery cdn on your layout and see if it works: `<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` (just to test)

Comment: if it works, maybe the installation you made of jquery on laravel is not correct. when you run npm install jquery, did you use npm run development or  npm run dev?

Comment: Jquery works, but only when I write scripts in `app.js` where I import jquery.